Describe the monodromy of a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$
I am currently studying monodromy from Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces" and I have the following problem: Let $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be defined via the map $z\mapsto z^3/(1-z^2)$. Then $f$ is a holomorphic map (where the projective line is seen as a Riemann surface) and has degree $3$ (which is the max of the degrees between the numerator and denominator). How can we find the Branch points? And using this, how can we find the corresponding permutations in $S_3$? (by Riemann existence theorem, we have a monodromy homomorphism $\rho:\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\Delta,p)\to S_d$, where $\Delta$ is the set of Branch points, $p\notin \Delta$ and $d$ is the degree of $f$).

It has a zero of order 3 at zero, a pole of order 1 at 1 and -1, and a pole of order 1 at infinity (either change coords or use the sum of degrees is 0), thus the only ramified point is at 0, I think then the monodromy is just a cyclic permutation at 0 between the three sheets
